# How to do a quadruple IF in excel

Tags: excel-formula

I would like to make an IF statement in Excel where if a certain cell equals to O, V, G or U another cell outputs 1, 2, 3 or 4 respectively.

I can't find any solution only, sorry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's probably a cleaner way to do this... but I'm not an excel expert.
If A1 is the cell you are checking to contain O V G or U:

```
=IF(A1="O", 1, IF(A1="V", 2, IF(A1="G", 3, IF(A1="U", 4, ""))))
```

The syntax of excel's if is: `If(condition, valueIfConditionIsTrue, valueIfConditionIsFalse)`

This is how excel interprets the command in a way that's easier for us to understand:

```py
if A1 == "O":
    output = 1
else:
    if A1 == "V":
        output = 2
    else:
        if A1 == "G":
            output = 3
        else:
            if A1 == "U":
                output = 4
            else:
                 output = ""
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest solution would be to create a look up table and then use a combination of the INDEX MATCH functions to grab the appropriate value. You can read more about INDEX MATCH here: https://exceljet.net/index-and-match

To start, create a table similar to this:

[image]

Then assuming you have a list of letters you are trying to match you can write a formula similar to this: =INDEX(Table1[Output],MATCH(E3,Table1[Letter],0)). If you want the formula to return blanks "" instead of #N/A, you can wrap the formula in an IFERROR:
=IFERROR(
        INDEX(Table1[Output],MATCH(E3,Table1[Letter],0))
     ,"")

Here's a picture of the final output.
[image]